# Any option for making AWS RDS Read replica writable for Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Currently I am using postgresql9.5 for my read replica. Also if possible please elaborate how I can implement master - master configuration for servers to be read-writable and 2 way synchronization

Answer (score 2):

A `PostgreSQL`  read replica(same or different region) is a physical copy, and PostgreSQL doesn't allow for a read replica to be made writable although you can promote a `PostgreSQL` read replica into a standalone DB instance.
[This](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-for-amazon-rds-postgresql-replication/) is a good read about best practices regarding RDS PostgreSQL read replicas replication

Comment: My original requirement is : I have a master server which gets locked when i perform schema related changes for multi-tenant application. As it gets locked for around one min, i could not perform any write operations. That is the reason I want rad replica to be writable